# Vector interpretation of Kepler's 2nd law ( r X a = 0 )

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, vectors

I just  read the vector interpretation of [Kepler's second law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_laws_of_planetary_motion) and the conclusion put me in a confusion.
The interpretation concludes by demonstrating that **r** X **a** = 0, where boldfaced r and a are respectively position vector of the planet from the sun and  the acceleration of the movement. The demonstration is interpretated as r and a being parallel to each other, which I understand but in the opposite direction and thus acceleration is directed towards the center is what I don't. How can we deduce  whether any two vectors are parallel in the same or the opposite direction just by analyzing the cross product?

Comment: We cannot deduce whether any two vectors are parallel in the same or the opposite direction just by analyzing the cross product. For another example, if ab=0 and a,b are real, then we cannot deduce that a=0 or b=0 or both are zero.

Comment: If it is so then how is it interpreted that the acceleration acts in the direction opposite to the position vector?

Comment: By Newton gravity law.

Comment: Kepler Second  Law, that "the line joining a planet and the Sun sweeps out equal areas during equal intervals of time", is this the same a geometric interpretation of  Newton's conclusion that under a central force the motion is on a plane with constant angular momentum. So there is no need to "interpret this interpretation" by the trivial result that the vector product of two collinear vectors is zero.

Answer (score 0):

The cross product of two vectors is the area of a parallelogram defined by those vectors. If the angle is 90 degrees then the cross product is simply the magnitude of vector 1 multiplied by the magnitude of vector 2 (i.e are of a rectangle). another way of writing the cross product is |v||u|sin(theta). If theta is 0 (both pointing in same direction) or 180 (opposite direction) then sin(theta) = 0. There is no area defined by them. 
Here you can see which area i'm talking about
[image]

Comment: thanks for the input. Yeah as I have written I understand that cross vector 0 means they have to be parallel. The only problem was I didn't understand how the author of the lesson that I read interpret that **a** is acting in the opposite direction (180 degrees) to **r**. Maybe as someone told he directly used Newton's Law.

Comment: ohh, well **a**=**F**/m The force vector is towards the sun so  a is towards the sun.